# How add starts with space and new line for regexp?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have regexp I want to add starts with space or new line. How I can add to my regexp. my regexp is `/:([a-zA-Z0-9-_+]+):/g`.

Comment: If you want to match optional leading word characters, try `^\w*[ \n]:([\w+-]+):` [js demo](https://ideone.com/eMdU4q)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prepend this expression `(?:\n| )` (which is newline or space) before your regex, which will mean that it can start with either a space or new line and also replace `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` with `\w` to modify your regex to this,

```
(?:\n| ):([\w+-]+):
```

```js
console.log(/(?:\n| ):([\w+-]+):/g.test(" :hey-how+r_u:"));
console.log(/(?:\n| ):([\w+-]+):/g.test("\n:hey-how+r_u:"));
console.log(/(?:\n| ):([\w+-]+):/g.test(":hey-how+r_u:"));
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/000Y7e/1)**

If you want to make that newline or space as optional, you can add `?` after this `(?:\n| )` and change your regex to this,

```
(?:\n| )?:([\w+-]+):
```

**[Demo with newline or space as optional](https://regex101.com/r/000Y7e/2)**

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. It was solving my problem. And console.log(/(?:\n| ):([\w+-]+):/g.test(":hey-how+r_u:")); in this case also it should find. And if the string is line hello:smile: it should not find.

Comment: Hi it is finding hello:hai: this is not a valid format for me.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const clear = /^\s*:([\w+-]+):/g.test(":smile:");
const nextstr = /^\s*:([\w+-]+):/g.test("\n:smile:");
const withspace = /^\s*:([\w+-]+):/g.test(" :smile:");
const letters = /^\s*:([\w+-]+):/g.test("asdasdas:smile:");

console.log(clear)
console.log(nextstr)
console.log(withspace)
console.log(letters)
```

Comment: not inside the shortcode before the shortcode it should start with space or new line

Comment: can you give example with data and expect result?

Comment: it should find :smile: or space :smile: or newline :smile: and also any string :smile: it should not find djfkdsjfk:smile:

Comment: i've changed my answer like you ask in comment

Comment: you can fix if remove start ^  symbol
  \s*:([\w+-]+):